# How can I display a line of text from a CSV file into a website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the below code, trying to create a basic truth or dare app, as a fun / silly way to learn to make a website.

I have a basic version that's working, but at the moment the javascript sets the dares on the webpage.

Was hoping to have it pulled from a CSV file that I can edit to add 100's in there quicker.

Any tips on doing this?

I want to be able to have different set of questions based on gender etc, moving into being able to pull from different 'difficulties'

At the moment they are coded into:

```
var maleDares = [
            "Sing a song from your favorite musical.",
            "Do an impersonation of your favorite celebrity.",
            "Dance like nobody is watching.",
            "Wear a silly costume and walk around the block."
        ];
        var femaleDares = [
            "Sing a song from your favorite musical.",
            "Do an impersonation of your favorite celebrity.",
            "Dance like nobody is watching.",
            "Wear a silly costume and walk around the block."
        ];
```

Any help / points in the right directions would be appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .tab {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .div {
        display: none;
      }
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        #playerList {
            width: 500px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 25px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        #playerList h3 {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        #playerList ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #playerList li {
            list-style: none;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        #playerList label {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #dare {
         
           
        }
        #dare h3 {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tab" id="tab1">Add Players</div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab2">Player List</div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab3">Play Game</div>
    <div class="div" id="div1">    <h3>Player List</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="playerName" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Gender:</label>
                <select id="playerGender">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="addPlayer">Add Player</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="div2">
    <div id="playerListDisplay"></div>
    
    
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="div3"><div id="dare">
        <h3>Dare</h3>
        <div id="dareDisplay"></div>
        <button id="generateDare">Generate Dare</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tab1').click(function(){
          $('#div1').show();
          $('#div2').hide();
          $('#div3').hide();
        });
        $('#tab2').click(function(){
          $('#div2').show();
          $('#div1').hide();
          $('#div3').hide();
        });
        $('#tab3').click(function(){
          $('#div3').show();
          $('#div1').hide();
          $('#div2').hide();
        });
      });
    </script>
    
     <script>
 var maleDares = [
            "Sing a song from your favorite musical.",
            "Do an impersonation of your favorite celebrity.",
            "Dance like nobody is watching.",
            "Wear a silly costume and walk around the block."
        ];
        var femaleDares = [
            "Sing a song from your favorite musical.",
            "Do an impersonation of your favorite celebrity.",
            "Dance like nobody is watching.",
            "Wear a silly costume and walk around the block."
        ];
        var players = [];

        document.getElementById("addPlayer").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var name = document.getElementById("playerName").value;
            var gender = document.getElementById("playerGender").value;

            if (name === "") {
                alert("Please enter a name!");
            } else {
                players.push({
                    name: name,
                    gender: gender
                });
                document.getElementById("playerName").value = "";
                updatePlayerListDisplay();
            }
        });

        document.getElementById("generateDare").addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (players.length === 0) {
                alert("Please add some players first!");
            } else {
                var randomPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
                var player = players[randomPlayer];
                var dare;
                if (player.gender === "male") {
                    dare = maleDares[Math.floor(Math.random() * maleDares.length)];
                } else {
                    dare = femaleDares[Math.floor(Math.random() * femaleDares.length)];
                }
                document.getElementById("dareDisplay").innerHTML = player.name + ": " + dare;
            }
        });

        function updatePlayerListDisplay() {
            var listHTML = "<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                listHTML += "<li>" + players[i].name + " (" + players[i].gender + ")</li>";
            }
            listHTML += "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("playerListDisplay").innerHTML = listHTML;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried the below but didn't work

```
let maleDares = [];

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('dares.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let lines = data.split('\n');
    let dares = lines.map(line => {
        let columns = line.split(',');
```

Comment: What specifically "didn't work" in your attempt?  If you tried to execute that code in a browser then, no, that certainly won't work.  That looks like an attempt at server-side code.  Which would be the ideal approach here.  If server-side functionality isn't available (e.g. if hosting static files is the only option) then you'd need to make an AJAX request to fetch the entire CSV file and choose an item from there.  (And JSON would probably be easier to code than CSV, but the latter isn't prohibitively difficult.)

Comment: Assuming the you wanted to edit questions easily & If your data is just list of sentences you don't even need csv. You can use 2 plain text files m.txt and f.txt files. Use `fetch()`  with `.text()` in callback to load them & then split them by newlines "\n" to get arrays.

Comment: if you want to have more categories, just create more files: f-easy.txt, f-medium.txt, f-hard.txt etc

Comment: Keep in mind this will be a limited learning experience that wouldn't work in the "real world". Web pages and javascript are executed on the users machine. Once this is hosted on a webserver the local csv file will no longer be available. You will then need some kind of server side technology to read and parse the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

My answer just for inspiration, how you can solve it: Plain text for the tasks should suffice for your needs. Assuming that your files "f.txt" & "m.txt" are in the data folder:
You can use pass `fetch` to `Promise.all` with `.text()` in callback to get the contents. Then, the returned array of file contents are `split` by new lines in map function, filter is used to remove empty strings (empty newlines). You can get the individual arrays using destructure syntax.

```
Promise.all([
  fetch('data/f.txt').then(r => r.text()),
  fetch('data/m.txt').then(r => r.text())
]).then((arrOfTxtFM) => {

const arrOfDareItemsFM = arrOfTxtFM.map((item)=> item.split("\n").filter(item => item));
const [fDaresArr,mDaresArr]= arrOfDareItemsFM;

console.log(fDaresArr)
console.log(mDaresArr)

});
```